# Replicated site using htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a complete newb to the RewriteRule so I'm asking for some help here.  I have a website that I want to make replicated.

When someone signs up to the site they create their own replicated site, 
For example: mydomain.com/TheirWebsiteName

So when someone comes to their url: mydomain.com/TheirWebsiteName I want my server to process that as mydomain.com/index.php?aid=TheirWebsiteName

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I gave it a shot, and I received a 404 error. The index.php file is definitely there, I can go to it directly... any  ideas?

Comment: @user1324696 what's the URL you are using? When I put `http://localhost/TheirWebsiteName` in my browser and those rules in a blank htaccess file on a vanilla test instance of apache, I get served the content of `/index.php?aid=TheirWebsiteName`

Comment: @user1324696 it works for me and using that URL. Are you sure you have `AllowOverride All` so your htaccess file is actually being used? Do you have other rules that supercede these? Is mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Great questions.  I am not sure about AllowOverride All or the mod_rewrite however I suspect that they are enabled because I ran this code earlier:   
   `options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [nc]`
and it worked just fine.  I'm hosting on a shared platform, a company called Fatcow... I'm running the code exactly as you have it above in my .htaccess file.

Comment: @user1324696 does there happen to be a directory named 'john'?

Comment: No, there is no directory named john. The index.php page simply checks to see if the aid is set.  If it is, it redirects to intro.php if not it redirects to index2.php If I'm getting a 404 error it's leading me to believe that it's trying to redirect to a page other than those 3 mentioned but I don't know how to check to see where it's redirecting to. Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it!, this is dumb.  I had to wrap that in these tags: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>` and then it worked.  That may have been a given I did not know about.